# CosmosDb string search on numeric field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, azure-cosmosdb, aws-documentdb

I have fields in Cosmos DB like below

```
{
    "BatchId": "XYZ",
    "abc": "OK",
    "sdf": "324234",
    "sfd": "234",
    "DeType": "234",
    "werwe": "werwe",
    "werwer": "low",
    "GenerationTimeLiveMinutes": 129
}
```

Here i have a .net UI which has a search field. My requirement here is to display all the records based on search criteria provided. That is if i give "9" in GenerationTimeLiveMinutes( numeric field) it should display all the records which **contains** 9. 
 I can acheive this using UDF but we are not supposed to use UDF accordng to client. Can we acheive this using cosmos select query.

```
 select * from ABCCollection r where  BatchId='XYZ'
 AND Contains(r.CommandTimeToLiveMinutes,9)
```

Doesnot return any result
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-tostring) in your sql:

```
SELECT c.id,c.num FROM c
where contains(tostring(c.num),"9") = true
```

For you, the sql should be like:

```
select * from ABCCollection r where  BatchId='XYZ'
 AND Contains(Tostring(r.CommandTimeToLiveMinutes),"9") = true
```

Comment: What is tostring() here. I assume it is a UDF . I am not allowed to use any userdefned functions in cosmos db

Comment: Either store the field as string or use the casting function, those are the only option available,  ToString is the string built-in  system function which are available..

Comment: Not udf,it's built-in function used in the sql.Don't worry.

Comment: udf should be used like `udf.XXX()`  in sql.

Comment: @MohitVerma Yeah, agree with you.

Comment: Can you modify my asnwer with ToString which i can execute at azure cosmos db query window

Comment: @Coder I updated your sql with Tostring(), you could execute it in your query window directly. Please take a shot.

Comment: @Coder Sure,it's ok.

Comment: @Coder sorry,have no idea. i remember that it's always there when i searched it. Cosmos db is always being optimized and there are a lot of new features.

Comment: @ Jay Gong, Any view on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59209788/issue-with-cosmos-db-query-using-contains

Comment: @Coder Let me check!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK , Contains()  is a String Functions for Wildcard Searches and you can use conatins for string purpose only.

I have tried reproducing the same scenario and it worked like you mentioned as it didn't return any result when i tried to use it in numeric number.

I see the only option that you cast the numeric field in string and try to use contains on it. But that might require using UDF's in the first place.

Alternatively , i could think of different way of doing it but that would require schema changes which is that you can store the **`GenerationTimeLiveMinutes`** as a string in that way you will be able to search it easily.

Feel free to tag me in your conversation, hope it helps.

here are some tips and trick for using cosmos DB sql queries:

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/nosql-databases/sql-for-cosmos-db-tips-and-tricks/